# How to prevent ajax calls from Chrome developer tool?

Tags: javascript, ajax, csrf, csrf-protection

My Ajax call is protected by 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

However it is still possible to make some ajax calls from the Google Chrome tool.

Is there a way to prevent ajax calls from Google Chrome?

(An easy way to setup a CSRF protection?)

Comment: **NEVER TRUST THE CLIENT** - validation __must__ always happen on the server. People can always send arbitrary HTTP requests to your server.

Comment: Nope, if you'd be able to stop ajax calls from the console, you'd stop all ajax calls in the browser as well.

Comment: What actually you are trying to do? You want to have them disabled for debugging purposes?

Comment: On a less dramatic tone - this doesn't have anything to do with CSRF, CSRF is about cross-domain requests and is protected against with headers and anti forgery tokens. OWASP is a good place to start reading about it.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 6):

As Benjamin said on the first comment, never trust the client, you need to validate on the server side. But I can still give you a solution to prevent user to send Ajax requests from console.

you just need to make the `XMLHttpRequest` constructor private, then you can set it to `null`

```
(function (xhr) {
    // Your code here ...
    // Here you can send Ajax Requests without any problem
    // You just need to call the sendAjaxReq with options

    function sendAjaxReq(options) { 
         window.XMLHttpRequest = xhr;
         $.ajax(options);
         window.XMLHttpRequest = null;
    }

}(window.XMLHttpRequest));

window.XMLHttpRequest = null;
// Now you can't send Ajax requests from here, and not from console as well.
```